# Texture seams in Cycles, but not in Substance or Redshift

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I'm pretty new to Cycles and Blender as a whole, and am having issues with seams coming through when rendering with Cycles. [image]

I made the texture in Substance Painter and the seams didn't show up there. They also didn't show up when I tried them in Redshift. Thanks for any help you can give me on this!

Comment: hello, please pack the images (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) and share your object: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I think I figured it out. It was something wrong with my normal map coming from substance. Thanks!